# Node-Red: send the result values of a HTML dropdown list to an MQTT Topic

Tags: node-red

I am trying to program a custom Node-Red dashboard in HTML using the "template" node, setting a multiple-selection dropdown list with the days of the week, but I cant make it send the select values to an MQTT node as output. I have tried the following code based on sone Internet research:

```
<div ng-bind-html="msg.payload"></div>
<select multiple>
<option value="1">Monday</option>
<option value="2">Tuesday</option>
<option value="3">Wednesday</option>
<option value="4">Thursday</option>
<option value="5">Friday</option>
<option value="6">Saturday</option>
<option value="7">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

since this is not working, can anyone please help me? As it seems, I am not really experienced in HTML and have just started witn Node-RED...

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a multi-select pulldown showing in the dashboard now, right? Have you tried adding any events to it -- like an `onchange` event? Or are you wanting to only send the value(s) when a submit button is pressed?

Comment: My first thought was that after selecting an element from the list its value  should be automatically submitted. However after chacking some other HTML examples I realized that it is not possible. It is wirking now after I have made the following change on the "select" line: <select ng-model="msg.payload" ng-change="send(msg)" multiple>
this is by the way exactly what you have suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by changind the second line like this:
    `<select ng-model="msg.payload" ng-change="send(msg)" multiple>`